# Catching calling method name in IDbCommandInterceptor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, method-names

I am using `IDbCommandInterceptor` to catch Entity Framework queries. This way I can access some crucial information such as `DbParameter`s and `DbCommand` etc.

Bu I also need to get where this query is called from. I have tried to get this by by using `StackTrace` :

```
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
System.Reflection.MethodBase methodBase = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
```

This might work in regular method calls, but in this instance since I am intercepting the Entity Framework mechanism I don't see it is possible to get the calling method in my code.

Is it possible to get the calling method name automatically when an Entity Framework query has run?

Answer (score 0):

a bit late, but you were on the right track.

check https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/657, which will explain how you can get the info from the CallStack.

just a copy/paste from that link:

```
var stack = new StackTrace(true);
command.CommandText += "\r\n\r\n/********************* \r\n * "
    + string.Join("\r\n * ",
    (from f in stack.GetFrames().Skip(2)
        let m = f.GetMethod()
        select m?.DeclaringType.Name + "." + m?.Name + ":" + f.GetFileLineNumber())
    ) + "\r\n*********************/";
```

the downside is that calling the StackTrace on each DB interaction gives a huge performance hit. Be sure to properly test before putting this into any production environment.